# Remove all lists that have a certain item from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, boolean, list-comprehension, contains

I have a list of lists in python that looks like this:

`my_list = [[True, 0, 4], [True, 3, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]`

And I want to remove all lists that have *True* in them

I tried with

`my_list = [x for x in my_list if True not in x]`

but all I get is an empty list when obviously the result should be `[1, 3, 5]`

When I try with a list like `l = [[True, 0, 4], [3, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]` i get `[[3, 6, 7]]` and I don't understand why.

It seems to be a problem with *True* because when I try with an integer it removes the lists accordingly

Comment: `True == 1` equals True

Comment: Bool is a subclass of int (see duplicate) with base values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @LydiavanDyke notes, `True == 1`, so you would need to use the stronger `is` operator, which means you cannot use the simple `in` operator (which uses `==`).

```
my_list = [[True, 0, 4], [True, 3, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5]]
without_true = [
  sublist for sublist in my_list
  if not any(item is True for item in sublist)
]
```

will then give you

```
>>> without_true
[[1, 3, 5]]
```

note that `A in B` is functionally equivalent to (but typically quite faster than)

```
any(item == A for item in B)
```

Comment: Nice. It's probably more efficient then what I had in mind: ```[x for x in my_list if ("True" not in map(str, x))]```

Comment: Yeah, you avoid str-casting, false positive for "True" or objects that have a str/repr of "True", and in py27 an unnecessary list construction =)